# Is it safe to share single X509_STORE between multiple threads for verifying certificate?

Tags: c, multithreading, openssl

Use case: I want connections to be accepted and served in a network thread and delegate all certificate checking to another thread (or even thread pool). CA for all certificates to be checked is stored in a single `X509_STORE`. Basically, when certificate is received from a client, I create new `X509_STORE_CTX`, initialize it with a single (say, global) `X509_STORE`, and feed a worker thread with a checking routine which calls `X509_verify_cert`.

The question is, does this kind of thread-sharing of `X509_STORE` need any external locking provided by an application?

Particularly, I'm  worried because `X509_STORE_CTX_init` takes a non-const pointer of my `X509_STORE`. Probably, this is because this function modifies reference counters inside the store, which is thread-safe provided that locking callbacks are set during initialization of the library. There should be no other non-const access to the store, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it safe to share single X509_STORE between multiple threads for verifying certificate?

Yes, but with strings attached. The Yes is because OpenSSL provides locks for the store:

```
openssl-1.0.2h$ grep -IR CRYPTO_LOCK * | grep STORE
crypto/crypto.h:# define CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE          11
crypto/crypto.h:# define CRYPTO_LOCK_STORE               37
crypto/x509/by_dir.c:            CRYPTO_r_lock(CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE);
crypto/x509/by_dir.c:            CRYPTO_r_unlock(CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE);
crypto/x509/by_dir.c:        CRYPTO_w_lock(CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE);
crypto/x509/by_dir.c:        CRYPTO_w_unlock(CRYPTO_LOCK_X509_STORE);
...
```

However, the "strings attached" is you need to manually install the locks, which can be non-trivial. Also see:

- [Is OpenSSL thread-safe?](https://www.openssl.org/docs/faq.html#PROG1) from the OpenSSL FAQ
- [Threads(3) man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/threads.html)
- [Openssl thread-safety-callback-function registration with both direct call and indirect call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21874152) on Stack Overflow
- ...